# how can i set old input value on refresh in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

im using laravel and Vuejs

how can i set the input old value on refresh or back to the page in vue dynamic component

something like this :

```
value="{{ old('name') }}
```

Comment: Do you mean , you want to reset the value of your input on page refresh. An example or a way to reproduce will be quite helpful.

Comment: no no . imagine i have a vue component which that have some inputs and user will click (next) and another comonent will apear, when user click back in browser the inputs are clear and i want it to have their old values

Comment: Example: Input Element state changes from  initial_val -> temp_val -> new_val  and then you do a refresh.  Now, should the Input element be set to initial_val ?

Answer (score 1):

In your blade file, create a new script tag:

```
<script>
var oldFormData = {
  name: "{{ old('name') }}",
  //...
}
</script>
```

Then in your component `created` callback.

```
created() {
  this.name = oldFormData.name // This should get {{ old('name') }} value
}
```

You could also pass the old data via Vue component `props`.

Let's say your component is `my-form`, then it should look like this in your blade file:

```
<my-form :oldData="{name: '{{ old('name') }}'}"></my-form>
```

Then on `created`:

```
props: ['oldData'],
created() {
  this.name = this.oldData.name
}
```

Comment: sure . but my form is not in my blade. i have only the component tag in my blade and my form is in my vue component

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as the component is able to see `oldFormData` object.

Comment: when i bind a prop , that will not show into component. why?

Comment: Did you try the latest version of my answer?

Comment: yes. my props will pass to components normally . but not when i bind them

Comment: i think i can use session storages too